# Regarding using CLI terminals in python

Tags: python, command-line-interface

I have been trying to use Helics which is a co-simulation tool. I have been using the Jupyter Notebook and the python language. According to the base example provided in the user guide,the co-simulation should be executed from a `helics_cli`  terminal. I installed the terminal using `pip install git+git://github.com/GMLC-TDC/helics-cli.git@main`.

My problem is that I don't know how to access `helics_cli`. Is it possible to access it from the Jupyter Notebook itself or do I need to run a python script from the cmd?

Answer (score 1):

So...
if you want to install it and you have trouble accessing it, have you already tried using pip: pip install helics?
Here's documentation that I really found helpful!
https://docs.helics.org/_/downloads/en/main/pdf/
trying reading it, although it's a little long, if you go into page 4, it's all about installing there, so if that didn't help, I think the article will be a bit of a help.